# need Guide to create a membership to my plugin (license key)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

### Guide to create a membership to my plugin (license key)

hey I just finished programming my plugin and I need to make it Premium not free
for example, once someone installed my plugin on his site, the plugin will work for free for 10 days then the customer must pay and buy a license key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For create a separate API and generate for each email a token key and save it in client db wordpress , for every active plugin i create function to check if is there key saved in db and the key is valid !